# How to specify Content-Transfer-Encoding in jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

How do I specify

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
```

in the following:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: "http://localhost/mytest",
data: JSON.stringify({json : mydata}),
dataType: 'json',
```

I don't see it in the parameter options: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.  I have a json file that is coming as Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary (I see this in the mime info).  I'd like to emulate it that type.

Comment: json is not binary is it

Comment: ^^  If you want to set any additional key value pairs you can set it in the `header` property of the settings. See the documentation